# TCP Server StreamSocketListener event handler does not accept events in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have implemented UWP a TCP server in Win 10 Core on Raspberry Pi 3 following some examples. I have enabled my Raspberry Pi 3 firewall for the port I use. If the ConnectionReceived event handler is expressed as a delegate, the StreamSocketListener can connect and process the incoming client requests:

```
string serverPort = "8081"; 
StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(serverPort);

listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>{};
```

But the classical expression for the same event handler is not able to detect incoming client requests (to connect):

```
 string serverPort = "8081"; 
StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;
await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(serverPort);

private async void OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender,
                                                     StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args) {}.
```

Please advise me what causes this different behavior and how to fix the problem for the classical event handler.

Comment: Restarting Win 10 IoT seems to solved the problem. Still not clear what was the reason.

Comment: Did the client processor run on the same device? And did you run the app in debug mode or release mode with enabled .NET Native compilation?

Comment: The TCP server runs on Raspberry Pi 3. The TCP client is a separate desktop PC. Initially the approach with the delegate handler worked OK but the one with the explicit handler did not. Maybe after restarting the Win 10 IoT on the Raspberry Pi 3, an update was installed and the second approach works OK now.

Comment: Now, there are further problems with the OnConnectionReceived handler. First, when the TCP server is started and a request made from the remote PC to the server running on Raspbery Pi 3, the handler receives multiple triggers instead of just one, as expected. Second, if I even temporarily detach the handler in the beginning of its code, when a request is detected, a second request is necessary to be sent from the PC in order the DataReader to complete its processing. Please explain this behavior and how to fix it.

Comment: A line of code solved the need of multiple client requests:                     while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
{
 // append the obtained portion of the received data to the StringBuilder
 request.Append(dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength));

 // get the next portion of data from the InputStream
 >>>if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
  await dataReader.LoadAsync(256);                        
}